# How to say "From this date to X"?

Tags: time

How would you say, for instance;

"You may reach me on this number from today until 05.03.2020"?

Comment: "ab heute bis zum ..." - But "ab heute" wouldn't be used at all - It's clear we won't be called yesterday... So "bis ..." alone is fine.

Answer (score 5):

The three prepositions **von**, **ab** and **seit** can be used to mark the start of a period of time, the end is always marked with the preposition **bis**.

> Das Hallenbad ist vom 1. Juli bis zum 1. September geschlossen.

*The indoor pool is closed from July, 1st until Sep, 1st.*

> Das Hallenbad ist ab dem 1. Juli bis zum 1. September geschlossen.

*The indoor pool will be closed from July, 1st until Sep, 1st.*

> Das Hallenbad ist seit dem 1. Juli **und** (noch) bis zum 1. September geschlossen.

*The indoor pool has been closed since July, 1st **and** is (still) closed until Sep, 1st.*

(An additional **und** is required because of the change of perspective along the timeline.)

---

As others already wrote, it's unusual to write *"from today"*. If you ever had to do it, it's **von heute an**. Similar with *now* and *jetzt*.

***Starting from today*** I'm going to learn German.

> **Von heute an** lerne ich Deutsch.

BUT, often *ab* is preferred, specifically with **jetzt**.

*It's only ten minutes **starting from now**.*

> Es sind **ab jetzt** nur noch zehn Minuten.

Comment: Does it change anything if the dates also include the day of the week? Like: from Saturday, July 1st to Friday, September 1st. Would you still use the prepositions with an article (vom, ab dem, seit dem, bis zum)? Or would you drop it?

Comment: The *dem* after *ab* and *seit* is purely optional. You may put the day of week inbetween, or the name of a public holiday or similar, and may also leave the article out completely. The *dem* pulled into *zum* however is required. *Von* is the most tricky one: the article is required if you don't put a weekday or holiday name after it. And, in addition, *dem* may be replaced by a demonstrative pronoun in dative, too.

Answer (score 3):

"Sie erreichen mich unter dieser Nummer bis zum 05.03.2020."

or

"Sie können mich unter dieser Nummer bis zum 05.03.2020 erreichen."

You don't need to state "from today" ("ab heute") explicitly, because it's obvious nobody would call yesterday or even earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You could say:

> Sie können mich ab sofort (bis zum/einschließlich 05.03.2020) unter dieser/folgender Nummer
>   erreichen: ...

Or shorter:

> Sie erreichen mich ab sofort (bis zum/einschließlich 05.03.2020) unter dieser/folgender Nummer: ...

Both is polite. Use of *»ab sofort«* is good if your number has changed, otherwise it can be omitted.